# How to add red required text to an input when the field has not been filled out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a red required text on the right side of a text input. I would want it to look similar to this. [An email field with the required tag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ms4u.png)

I apologize for not have code to add, the only things ive tried have been messing with placeholders as i have no idea which direction to go for this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Here's a good place to start, hope this could point you in the right direction, as it's how I got started with HTML/CSS, especially when it came to input fields.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email.

Comment: A label would help with this, but first to be clear, do you want the Required to disappear when the user has started typing or is it to remain there? Do you really want it to look as though it is part of the input field? Would putting it just outside be good enough? The problem with putting it inside the input field is that it will interfere with (e.g. overwrite) a long email address, or you have to make it look as though it's part of an extended input field, but ensure it is separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider something like this.

```css
input {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 250px;
}
/* Position label on top of input field */
label {
  margin-left: -80px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
/* Show red label when input invalid */
input:required:invalid+label {
  color: red;
}
/* Don't display label when input is valid */
input:required:valid+label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email_input" placeholder="Email" required>
<label for="email_input">Required</label>
```

Comment: Hey @Gerard, Great solution, may I know why `relative` and `z index: 2` are needed here ... just curious :)

Comment: @Codenewbie the input and label elements are placed on top of each other. Hence the z-index. Z-index only works when position is used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Thank you, I just tried removing those two and it just worked fine so just thinking ..